# How to test a view that requires a user to be authenticated in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-testing

I have the following view that requires a user to be authenticated to access it, otherwise redirects to the login page:

In my `urls.py` file:

```py
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("settings", login_required(views.Settings.as_view()), name="settings"),
]
```

In my `views.py` file:

```py
class Settings(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, "project/settings.html")
```

How can I test this view?

Here is what I tried:

```py
class TestViews(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create(
            username="testUser",
            password="testPassword",
        )

    def test_settings_authenticated(self):
        client = Client()
        client.login(username="testUser", password="testPassword")
        response = client.get("/settings")
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, "project/settings.html")
```

But this returns a `302` status, implying the user was not authenticated.

Comment: Instead of `User.objects.create(...)` use `User.objects.create_user(...)` since the `create` method will not automatically hash the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead of User.objects.create(...) use User.objects.create_user(...) since the create method will not automatically hash the password.

This solved my problem.